# pagination using react, react-router, and redux

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

So I am making an ecommerce site using react, react-router v4, react-router-redux, and react-redux.

I have a Products page which lists all the products. The list of products are in my redux store. I do it this way as i can then use brand filters and price range filters to re-render the relevant products into my list.

What i would now like to do is have a certain amount of products listed per page, and have a pagination to allow me to cycle through the pages of products.

I have found methods for adding pagination, i think this part seems straight forward enough. The part I am struggling with is how do I tell my component which part of the products to render on each page of the pagination cycle??

this is how my container component looks right now:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import changeBrandFilter from '../actions/changeBrandFilter';
import changePriceFilter from '../actions/changePriceFilter';

import KitsOverview from './KitsOverview';
import Filter from './Filter';
import ProductsListItem from './ProductsListItem';
import FilterCSS from './Filter.css';

class KitsPage extends React.Component{
    createBrandFilterList() {
        return this.props.brandFilters.map(filter => {
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.brand}
                    id={filter.brand}
                    changeFilter={() => this.props.changeBrandFilter(filter)}
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                    disabled={filter.disabled}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createPriceRangeFilterList() {
        return this.props.priceRangeFilters.map(filter => {
            return (
                <Filter
                    key={filter.priceRange}
                    id={filter.priceRange}
                    changeFilter={() => this.props.changePriceFilter(filter)}
                    inuse={filter.inuse}
                    disabled={filter.disabled}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    createKitsProductsList() {
        if(this.props.products.length > 0) {
            return this.props.products.map(product =>{
                return (
                    <ProductsListItem
                        key={product.id}
                        brand={product.brand}
                        model={product.model}
                        price={product.price}
                        image={product.image}
                        link={"/kitproducts/"+product.id}
                    />
                )
            })} else {
                return <div>No products match the filter criteria selected above.</div>
            } 
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <KitsOverview />
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="filtersList col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        Filter by Brand:
                        <div>
                            {this.createBrandFilterList()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="filtersList col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        Filter by Price Range:
                        <div>
                            {this.createPriceRangeFilterList()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div>
                        {this.createKitsProductsList()}
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    let brandFilters = state.kitsBrandFilters;
    let priceRangeFilters = state.kitsPriceRangeFilters;
    let products = state.kitsProducts;
    let filtered_products = products;
    let activeBrandFilters = brandFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activeBrandFilters.forEach(filter => {
        filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
            product => product.brand === filter.brand
        )
    });
    let activePriceRangeFilters = priceRangeFilters.filter(
        item => item.inuse === true
    );
    activePriceRangeFilters.forEach(filter => {
        filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(
            product => product.priceRange === filter.priceRange
        );
    });
    return {
    brandFilters: brandFilters,
    priceRangeFilters: priceRangeFilters,
    products: filtered_products
    };
};

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({changeBrandFilter: changeBrandFilter, changePriceFilter: changePriceFilter}, dispatch);
};

export const KitsPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(KitsPage);
```

Comment: are you getting all items from your backend at once and just showing different "pages" or are you making separate API calls each time you paginate through the results?

Comment: I feel like some information is missing here, and it would be helpful to know what you've tried thus far as I see no logic here for implementing pagination. Also, please specify the type of pagination you are attempting to implement... offset-based or cursor-based. Your design choice will certainly change how you approach this. Offset-based which uses enumeration will require knowing the offset, limit, and total whereas cursor-based needs to know the initial position and then have a pointer to the current position and a count to know how much to increment by.

Comment: I have no API currently setup canaan, I was hoping i could do this all on the front end?

Comment: HI Scot, thanks for your reply, I have tried a node module (paginatr) which seems really good at first glance but i kept getting the error no such function as this.pagination, even though it instructs me to do this in the module example codes. I am sorry if i have left it very vague, i guess what i want to know is, do I have to make new arrays of the products received from my store, within the actual component?

Comment: Since you have no current API currently setup, you can load the records page by page. LIMIT(offset, limit) is a useful function in MySQL you could use. If you choose to load all of the records at once, you would have to choose some sort of order so certain ones have precedence over others (e.g. id 1 before id 100). Then, simply filter out the records based on the number of pages you have and the page you are on. records = limit(limit*currentPage, limitNum)